# Difference in telnet of amazon ec2 instance using internal and public IP

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a 4 node hadoop cluster on ec2. We have configured **Hortonworks Hadoop (HDP version 2.4)** through Ambari.
I have opened all traffic for our all four instances internally and the office external IP.
Whenever I do telnet within the cluster using internal IP:

`telnet <internal_ip> 2181`

It is able to connect to the specific port I have my service(zookeeper) running on.

When I use public IP of the same instance(Elastic IP) instead of internal IP, I am not able to telnet either within the cluster or from my office IP:

`telnet <elastic_ip> 2181`

I have already configured security group to allow all traffic. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. We are not using any other firewall except AWS security group.

Please suggest how can I connect using Elastic IP/Public IP of my instance on this port.

Please find the screenshot of Security Group of EC2: [image: Security Group EC2]

Comment: The problem is resolved now. The issue was with Office firewall. The port was not opened for outbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the default VPC ?

If not, check if the VPC has an Internet Gateway, the Route table (you need a route to the Internet Gateway) and the Networks ACLs.

The Route table and Network ACLs are applied to a subnet.
The default VPC is configured to allow outside traffic, not a new VPC.

Or, the Elastic IP is linked to the same network interface ? The Elastic IP is linked to a network interface of an instance.

EDIT: you can take a look on AWS doc for a better explanation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html